# Retrieving data from two different models in codeigniter and showing it in one view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CI and I wanted to know how to retrieve data from different models but the same views.

I have 2 models, one for the breakdown of assessment of fees and the other one is the total price of the breakdown of assessment of fees.

```
    function result_getAssessment($studentid)
            {

                $sql=
                "
                select g.studentid, sb.subjectcode, s.price
                FROM grades g
                INNER JOIN subjectblocking sb ON g.blockcode=sb.blockcode
                INNER JOIN subjects s ON sb.subjectcode=s.subjectcode
                WHERE studentid='$studentid'
                ";

                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                $result = $result->result();
                return $result; 

            }

function result_totalAssessment($studentid)
        {
            $sql=
            "
            SELECT sum(s.numofunit) total_units, sum(s.price) total_tuition FROM subjects s
            INNER JOIN subjectblocking sb ON s.subjectcode=sb.subjectcode
            INNER JOIN grades g ON sb.blockcode=g.blockcode
            WHERE g.studentid='$studentid'
            ";

            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $result->result();
            return $result; 
        }
```

My Controllers:

```
 function getAssessment() 
{
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('navbar');
   $this->load->view('sidebar');
   $this->load->view('footer');
   $studentid = $this->session->userdata('studentid');
   $data['studentid'] = $studentid;
   $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_getAssessment($studentid);
   $this->load->view('v_assessment',$data);
   $this->gettotalAssessment();
}

  function gettotalAssessment() 
{
   $studentid = $this->session->userdata('studentid');
   $data['studentid'] = $studentid;
   $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_totalAssessment($studentid);
   $this->load->view('v_assessment',$data);
}
```

My view:

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row){ ?>

              <tr>
              <td> <?php echo $row->subjectcode;?> <br></td>
              <td> <?php echo $row->price;?><br></td>
              <td> <?php echo $row->total_tuition;?><br></td>
              </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Please help me, how can I retrieve data from two models and displaying it from one view. Thanks in advance!

Comment: load two models in controller

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I did. I have 2 controllers for it too

Comment: you cant call another controller into another in codeigniter untill you autoload it with custom base controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are calling `$this->gettotalAssessment();` function after loading view in `getAssessment()` you need to do like this in your controller

```
function getAssessment() 
{
   $this->load->view('header');
   $this->load->view('navbar');
   $this->load->view('sidebar');
   $this->load->view('footer');
   $studentid = $this->session->userdata('studentid');
   $data['studentid'] = $studentid;
   $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_getAssessment($studentid);
   $data['totalAssessment'] = $this->m_login->result_totalAssessment($studentid);
   $this->load->view('v_assessment',$data);

}
```

In your view then your can access total Assessment by

```
$totalAssessment
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D So i should have one controller, now i know ^^

Answer (score 2):

This seems trivial in the ,[codeigniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html). Although am relatively new to codeigniter my contribution may be handy. Here it goes: 
make sure you load the two models (say in your controller class constructor).
Then there are these two lines in your code that are causing the problem

```html
1. $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_getAssessment($studentid); <<<found in getAssessment() method
```

and

```html
2. $data['query'] = $this->m_login->result_totalAssessment($studentid); <<<found in  gettotalAssessment()  method
```

You have to specify different array keys for these results 
since you are building the array somewhat dynamically. see: [php manual](http://tz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)
Note also that when you add an alement to an array while specifying an existing index, the value at that index becomes overridden by the new value. hope this throws more flesh to you solution search.

Comment: Thank you so much King! This sure is handy :D